# Flutter bottomNavBar with FAB button not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

So starting out I have this simple bottomNavBar which changes pages. What I wanted to do was add a FAB bar in the middle.

*original bottomNavBar*
[image: original bottomNavBar]

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    currentIndex: 0,
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0066EE),
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Home', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Diary', icon: Icon(Icons.book)),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Plans', icon: Icon(Icons.spoke_rounded)),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'More', icon: Icon(Icons.more)),
    ],
    onTap: (index) {
      if (index == 1) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              final foodItemsModel =
                  Provider.of<FoodItemsModel>(context, listen: false);
              return MealPlanPage(mealList: foodItemsModel.foodItems);
            },
          ),
        );
      } else if (index == 2) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return PlanPage();
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

*desired bottomNavBar*
[image]

My attempt of including the FAB bar involved wrapping the existing bottomNavBar in a **bottomAppBar** and then adding the **floatingActionButton**, the reason was because I assumed it was caused by BottomAppBar having a height that is larger than the bottomNavBar.
[image]

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: 0,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0066EE),
      selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Home', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Diary', icon: Icon(Icons.book)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Plans', icon: Icon(Icons.spoke_rounded)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'More', icon: Icon(Icons.more)),
      ],
      onTap: (index) {
        if (index == 1) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                final foodItemsModel =
                    Provider.of<FoodItemsModel>(context, listen: false);
                return MealPlanPage(mealList: foodItemsModel.foodItems);
              },
            ),
          );
        } else if (index == 2) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return PlanPage();
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
```

I tried setting the height of the **bottomAppBar** to match the height of the **bottomNavBar** but just ended up with a mess and improper FAB button placement still.
[image]

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Color(0xFF0066EE),
    elevation: 0,
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: 0,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0066EE),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Home', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Diary', icon: Icon(Icons.book)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Plans', icon: Icon(Icons.spoke_rounded)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'More', icon: Icon(Icons.more)),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          if (index == 1) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  final foodItemsModel =
                      Provider.of<FoodItemsModel>(context, listen: false);
                  return MealPlanPage(mealList: foodItemsModel.foodItems);
                },
              ),
            );
          } else if (index == 2) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return PlanPage();
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In android there's no problem with it. I think you are using ios.
This can happen when you have `SafeArea` if you have it set `bottom` property to `false`.

Or if you don't have `SafeArea`, try to set notchMargin property of BottomAppBar to 0.
example:

```
   BottomAppBar(
    notchMargin: 0,
    color: Colors.black,
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: (v) {}, items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: 
      Icon(Icons.baby_changing_station),label: ""),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),label: ""),
    ]),
  ),`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your main `MaterialApp` or the `Parent Widget` if there is any `margin` or `Padding` set, Because otherwise your code should work.

Working Code:

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Bottom Navigation Bar Demo'),
        ),
        body: _pages[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedFontSize: 14,
          unselectedFontSize: 14,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey, 
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.headphones),
              label: 'Headphones',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Output:

[image]